# How to mysql date to var obj [new date?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime, google-visualization

I am working on a project where I am having issues with dates formatting. I don't understand how to format the date from mysql (phpmyadmin) to this format, is this datetime in phpmyadmin or date ?

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/yaqew/1/edit

```
[new Date(1387717021701),   1],
[new Date(1387719023801),   2],
[new Date(1387721025901),   4],
[new Date(1387723027001),   8],
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #chart_div {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
    }   
</style>

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var obj = [
            [new Date(1387717021701),   1],
            [new Date(1387719023801),   2],
            [new Date(1387721025901),   4],
            [new Date(1387723027001),   8],
        ];

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Buy');
        data.addRows(obj)


        var options = {
            curveType: "function",
            width: 500, 
            height: 400,
            vAxis: {maxValue: 10}, 
            title: 'test',
            hAxis: {
                format: "HH:mm"
                //format: "HH:mm:ss"
                //format:'MMM d, y'
            },
            explorer: { 
                actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'], 
                axis: 'vertical'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
                            document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that PHP? (the new Date(...)) ??

Comment: JavaScript uses the Unix timestamp with a millisecond resolution.

Comment: How can I format the date correct in PhpMyAdmin to javascript will understand it ?

Comment: like CBroe said just convert your timestamp in millisecond.

Comment: Do I have to convert into millisecond? Is it not any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: When I change the date/time http://jsbin.com/suzisiwe/1/edit   I get the correct date and time but in the X axis it doesnt show.

Answer (score 0):

To use CBroe's suggestion:

SQL has a timestamp field OR you can use an int(11) to store the unit.

You can also before sending it inside mysql if you don't like timestamp you can convert it by doing 
`.toUTCString()` from the variable to get something as explained here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp

Answer (score 0):

Javascript also has the option of constructing Date objects like this:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Where `year` is a 4-digit year, `month` is zero-indexed (so January is `0`, not `1`), and `day` is the day of the month.  All arguments after `month` are optional.  If left off, the defaults are `day` = `1` and `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, and `milliseconds` are `0`.  Any argument that is out of bounds for the expected range will overflow to the appropriate degree.  Examples:

```
new Date(2014, 0) // January 1, 2014 00:00:00:000
new Date(2014, 1, 6) // February 6, 2014 00:00:00:000
new Date(2014, 4, 12, 0, 14) // May 12, 2014 00:14:00:000
new Date(2014, 0, 100) // April 10, 2014 00:00:00:000
new Date(2014, 1, 100) // May 11, 2014 00:00:00:000
new Date(2014, 0, 1000) // September 26, 2016 00:00:00:000
new Date(2014, 0, 0) // December 31, 2013 00:00:00:000
new Date(2014, -1) //  December 1, 2013 00:00:00:000
```

Non-integer inputs are truncated, however:

```
new Date(2014, 1, 6.8) // February 6, 2014 00:00:00:000
```